# acmart: figure not showing

Tags: floats, acmart

I'm using `\documentclass[acmtog]{acmart}`.
I have a few figures one after another.
One of them is not showing. The figure numbering is like it's still there, and there's a blank page where the figure should be.

If I omit the `[acmtog]`, then the paper dimensions are a bit different, and the figure shows fine.

```
\documentclass[acmtog]{acmart} % ...?
%\documentclass{acmart} % fine

\begin{document}
\title{paper}

\begin{teaserfigure}
    \caption{teaser}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
    \caption{hi--I'm here}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{hi2--where am I?}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, add a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` showing the issue. If I try a simple document, I see the figures.

Comment: added ("10 more to go...")

Answer (score 2):

It seems that figures that are too near the end of the document have the tendency to disappear when the last page balancing is performed.

If I add text then the figures appear.

```
\documentclass[acmtog]{acmart} % ...?
%\documentclass{acmart} % fine
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{paper}
\author{Name}
\acmConference{A}{B}{C}
\maketitle

\begin{teaserfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\Description{A}
\caption{teaser}
\end{teaserfigure}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}

\Description{B}
\caption{hi--I'm here}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image}
\Description{C}\ddt
\caption{hi2--where am I?}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it still sounds like a bug to me. For one, it doesn't happen without the 'acmtog'. Also, I don't like to shuffle things around until something works; it gives the feeling that latex is clunky.

Comment: @ZoharLevi Report the issue to the maintainer of the class, who's usually very responsive.

Comment: I'll try, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Balance package is rather fragile in many situations.  The new option `pbalance` uses a package `pbalance` by Nelson Lago to correct it.  So far this option is experimental (and avaialble in the development version https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart). If it works well, it will be the default.

In your case `\documentclass[acmtog, pbalance]{acmart}` works with the development version fine.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, I had to remove my figure in the ACM Appendix to far earlier in the Appendix. As noted, text needs come after where you insert the figure...and not just one sentence...This is not ideal given logical flow of content.